# Openshift accessing my app every 2 seconds?

Tags: openshift

I was seeing my sessions files folder of my new (created just today) php app, so I realized there are many files being generating. Then I opened `php.log` and saw that my app is being accessed every 2 seconds from the same IP (named `haxproxy_status_ip` in the `$_SERVER array`).

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You have an OpenShift scaled application, which uses HAProxy. What you are seeing is the HAProxy instance performing health checks of your application. This is totally normal. Read [this](http://blog.openshift.com/how-haproxy-scales-openshift-apps) if you want more information.